# Solve $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}{\biggl[(1+\cot x)^{\tan x}\biggr]^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate the limit: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}{\biggl[(1+\cot x)^{\tan x}\biggr]^3}$$

Could someone help me to solve this limit?

I found the answer in symbolab, however I could not understand how the steps are explained.

Please explain this to me. Thank you.

Comment: And this should be done without the use of l'Hopital?

Comment: In symbolab, it said that it is possible to solve using the euler limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = \tan x$. Then:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}{\biggl[(1+\cot x)^{\tan x}\biggr]^3} = \displaystyle\lim_{y \to \infty}{\biggl[\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y}\biggr]^3} = e^3.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any condition when we would like to substitute something in limits?

Comment: One can substitute to transform the limit into known forms, which in general have something like $x \to 0$ or $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Okay then, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Although the easier way has already been shown, we usually solve the limits of the form $1^{\infty}$ by taking the natural logarithm on both sides.

So, if we call the limit as $L$, then we have

$\begin{align} 
\ln L&=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\ln {\biggl[(1+\cot x)^{\tan x}\biggr]^3}\\ 
&=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} 3\tan x \ln {(1+\cot x)} \\
&=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{3\ln {(1+\cot x)}}{\cot x} \\ 
&=3 \hspace{100pt} \left(\text{Since} \color{red}{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x} =1}\right) \\
\end{align}$

Therefore $L=e^3$.